# .htaccess redirect from index.php not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I did my best to search in stack overflow questions and answers and even when I tried to apply a solution, it is not working.

I need to redirect all adresses, that begin with

http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=XX

to

http://www.example.com/XX

This is what I try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php\?lang\=)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

The location /index.php?lang=en **is not** redirecting /en (anywhere).
It is at the same URL.

Comment: By not working what do you mean? The user still ends up at http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=en    - is this what you mean?

Comment: I have to be completely confused. I need to end up at example.com/en

Comment: Yes, but where is the user currently ending up? At http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=en   (so in other words, no redirect) ?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is not redirected. Sorry I was not clear.

Comment: To rewrite a request based on the contents of the query string, have a look at the Apache httpd wiki article on this topic: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

In short, RewriteRule has access to the requested URI, not including the QUERY_STRING. For that, you need RewriteCond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match a query_string in a rewriterule. You need a specific RewriteCond for it. It should be more or less like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1 [R=302,L,QSD]
```

Comment: Correction: It IS working now, after you've updated the answer. Thank you. I'll check it precisely and come back.

Comment: The ^ indicates the start of the string, nothing else is needed since you are not capturing anything and yes I added a QSD (query string discard) to avoid a rewrite loop. Thanks to @Rich Bowen for reminding it to me.

Comment: Thank you for perfect answer: ezra-s and @RichBowen for useful contribution as well.

Comment: @ezra-s you actually don't need to use `QSD`, You can simply use the `?` to discard query string.  `http://www.example.com/%1?`

Comment: @PanamaJack Didn't know that, thanks for sharing it.